# Java import statement: what is import net.?

Tags: java, import

I was looking at this answer by Vivin Paliath and came across something that I've never seen before. This import statement was in his code:

```
import net.vivin.digit.DigitImage;
```

I've never seen any import net. statements before and when I wrote his code into Eclipse, I was given the error message that the import net could not be resolved, and as a result the class needed for the code to work (the DigitImage class) could not be resolved to a type.

I have seen this import net. is a few of Vivin Paliath's answers, but I had never seen it before. As such I have no idea what the error has to do with. I did some research but couldn't find any answers. Is this just an Eclipse problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing you need a .jar file.

Answer (score 4):

The naming convention is that `net.vivin.*` is written/owned by whoever owns the `vivin.net` Internet domain. If you go to http://vivin.net/, you'll see that it's the site of Vivin Paliath.

Answer (score 2):

This is not part of the java JDK. Instead, it's a library or another class that the user has added.